# Jquery, Call is only done one time successfully and after that it stays on the same result

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem concerning my code which should change content in a div onclick "More News articles" as the change will happen only once. I see in Chrome Developer mode that it fires every click a request. What goes wrong?

Output.php

```
<?php
require_once('../pe13f/SSI.php');
require_once ('../PE13/smf_2_api.php');
?>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function MakeRequest(id)
{
    $.ajax({
        url : 'display.php',
        data:{"id":id},
        type: 'GET',

        success: function(data){
            $('#streaminnern').html(data);
        }
    });
}
</script>

<div id="stream" class="bg4 roundedcrop shadow">
  <div class="ph25 pv20">
    <h1>News</h1>
    <input id="streamcnt" name="streamcnt" type="hidden" value="" />
  </div>
  <div id="streamadd"></div>
  <div id="streaminnern">


<?php 
$num_recent = 5;
echo $num_recent;
?> 

</div> 
    <div onclick="MakeRequest(<?php echo $num_recent; ?>);" id="streammore">More News articles</div>
</div>
```

backend php display.php

```
<?php 
$num_recent = $_GET['id']+5;
echo $num_recent; 
?>
```

Greetings Emil

Comment: Why wouldn't it fire on every click, that is what you're telling it to do ?

Comment: Why DB? it's not at all connected to a DB in this state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the source that is produced by output.php. You'll find there onclick="MakeRequest(5);". Basically - on every click you call MakeRequest(5) which always fires call display.php?id=5 (you probably see that in your dev console).

Try something like this:

```
<script>
var lastId = 0; // var that stores last fetched ID
function MakeRequest(id)
{
    if(!lastId) // if there is no last ID use the one from initial onclick
        lastId = id;

    $.ajax({
        url : 'display.php',
        data:{"id":lastId}, // note that we are using the lastId var
        type: 'GET',

        success: function(data){
            $('#streaminnern').html(data);
            lastId = data;  // save fetched ID in our global var
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The request is always the same.  Suppose `$num_recent` is initially set to 5.

Then as per your code `MakeRequest(5)` will be executed. And your ajax call updates a div with class  `streaminnern`. So the new id has no impact on the next ajax call. For the ajax request to be sent updated value you may set

```
$.ajax({
        url : 'display.php',
        data:{"id":$('#streaminnern').html()}, 
       .................
  });
```